# Django file upload: redirect views keep returning errors

Tags: python, django, file-upload, django-views

I have been working on this music site in Django, basically just trying to get the upload view to work. When you upload a music file, I want it to redirect to the results page. I have been having real trouble with trying to get the redirect to work and it should be very simple but just has not been working. Any help would be greatly appreciated!! My error:

> ValueError at /uploads/home/
>   The view uploads.views.upload didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

uploads/views.py (relevant buggy code):

```
def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('uploads:results')

        else:
            form = UploadFileForm()
        return render(request, 'uploads/upload.html', {'form': form})
```

uploads/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

    app_name = 'uploads'

    urlpatterns = [
        path('home/', views.upload, name='index'),
        path('<int:audiofile_id>/results/', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
    ]
```

upload.html (the upload template)

```
{% extends 'uploads/base.html' %}

{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-8">
            {% for audiofile in audiofiles %}
              <h1>{{ audiofile.title }}</h1>




        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-8">
      <form action="{% url 'uploads:results' audiofile_id %}" method="post" name = "form" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        </div>

        <!--<div class="row">-->
        <!--    <div class="col-lg-8">-->
        <!--<img src="{% static "uploads/loveLogo.jpg" %}" alt="lovelogo" class="img-fluid">-->
        <!-- </div>-->
        <!-- </div>-->
         </div>

 {% endblock %}
```

Comment: You've got that error when you access to `/uploads/home/` right? or after you click submit on the form?

Comment: accessing uploads/home, yes. It's because my redirect on submit is wrong tho

Comment: Oh yeah I see, your upload view just a part which relevant to the bug, not the whole view function.

Comment: Yes, correct this is only for one view as my other views are working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are trying to redirect to the url `results` but this url also takes the `audiofile_id` as the parameter which you haven't passed while redirecting so you need to change your view with this :

```
   if form.is_valid():
        file = form.save()
        return redirect('uploads:results',file.audiofile_id)
```